# Run a c# console application in build process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, msbuild, build-process

Suppose we have a solution with three projects:

[image]

1. `DownloadDataBase` is a console application that downloads data from web and creates a `sqlite` db file
2. `Test` is the main windows from application that uses the downloaded `sqlite` database.
3. `TestLibrary` is a class library that is referenced by the Test project.

I know How I can reorder the build of these three projects using `Configuration Manager` from build menu. But **The main question is :** How can I customize build process of the solution so that:

- It first builds the `DownloadDataBase`
- Then executes this console application `DownloadDataBase`
- After that copy the created `sqlite` file from the last step to the resource directory of the `Test` Project
- And Finally builds the `Test` project using the updated `sqlite` file?

Therefore every time that I build the new release I will have the latest data needed by my application.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have a look to "compile events" in each project properties. Maybe is what you are looking for

Comment: Would this be running locally or on a tfs build server? if tfs: you can define custom steps in the build template (the xaml file). locally: make a standalone executable of the "DownloadDatabaseProject" and start it as pre-builld step of your Test program (you can set it in properties of the test projects, its under the build events tab)

Comment: @NickOtten Not XAML anymore ;P XAML is dead in TFSBuild

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Even more reason for me to start nagging at my boss for an update

Comment: @NickOtten Yeah, and XAML was a nightmare...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to customize your MSBuild project files (i.e. `.csproj` files).

For example, in your *DownloadDatabase* project, add at the bottom of the XML file, inside the `<project>` element:

```
<Target AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).$(OutputType)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)file.db" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)Test" />
</Target>
```

Maybe there's some mistake, but at the end of the day, you need to use MSBuild tasks to perform these actions.

See [Exec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) and [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) MSBuild task documentation pages to get further details.

Comment: In case you have space in between the file names or any parent folders, you will get error 
exited with code 9009